# What does 's' stand for in auto-complete tips?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I use [auto-complete](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/) in Emacs, there come out "s" "v" "f" as description?
 If you have ac, type some lisp function in *scratch* and ac show you the tips, there is a "s" there, type add for example, and ac helps to come out "add-hook" and so on...

f means function, interactive ones?
v means variable.
what about s, functions without interactive?

And... how to get the document of a "s" function, like "cc-mode"?
C-h f failed.

Comment: Were you looking for something like this: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html#Interactive-Codes?

Comment: I am afraid your question is still not clear. How/where are you doing auto-complete. Your question needs to be elaborated before it can be understood.

Comment: no, if you have ac, type some lisp function  in *scratch* and ac show you the tips,there is a "s" there

Comment: I am using cygwin XEmacs and Emacs on windows. I have never heard of an *auto*-completion but when I do completion (M-TAB) in \*scratch\* I see completions. The functions have <f> suffix but I don't see an <s>. Can you paste a screenshot?

Comment: Thx.IronMensan said that s means symbol. I get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a chart in section 9.8.7 (near the bottom of the document) here: http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html that says that s means symbol.

Comment: thanks a lot. so how can I get the document of the symbol,like cc-mode or add-hook?

Comment: M-x apropos cc-mode tell me it's a plist

Comment: `M-x describe-symbol` might be a bit easier since it supports tab-completion of symbols.  I'm kind of surprised that auto-complete doesn't provide popup documentation of symbols too...